# android check box in alert dialog not showing

Tags: android, checkbox, android-alertdialog

Hello I am trying to show an alert dialog with a checkbox in order to allow the user to select the option 'Don't show again this dialog'. The dialog is showing but the checkbox doesn't. here is my code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBack;   
dialogBack = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
dialogBack.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.msg_attention));
dialogBack.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.msg_photo_caution));
dialogBack.setCancelable(false);

dialogBack.setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.confirm_continue),
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogBack, int which) {
            dialogBack.dismiss();

            beginTakeSupervisorPhoto();
        }
    });

dialogBack.setNegativeButton(context.getString(R.string.confirm_cancel),
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogBack, int which) {
            dialogBack.dismiss();

        }
    });


final CharSequence[] items = {context.getString(R.string.msg_dont_show_again)};
dialogBack.setMultiChoiceItems(items, null,
    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int        indexSelected,boolean isChecked) {
             Log.e("ListaClientesActivity.java","isChecked: "+isChecked);
                 if (isChecked) {
                 showPhotoWarning = false;
                 dataUtil.putBoolean(Constantes.SHOW_PHOTO_WARNING, false);
             }else{
                 showPhotoWarning = true;
                 dataUtil.putBoolean(Constantes.SHOW_PHOTO_WARNING, true);
             }
             dataUtil.savePreferences();

             }
});


dialogBack.create().show();
```

It is strange because it worked for me when I was using a Text View for the dialog:

```
dialogBack.setView(myMsg);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My idea is just remove `dialogBack.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.msg_photo_caution));` and your code well works well. It seems like you can't set both `Message` and `MultiChoiceItems`. You can put your message into the title or add your own layout to dialog by `setView`
**Edit:**
code for setting view:

```
TextView message = new TextView(context);
message.setText(context.getString(R.string.msg_photo_caution));
CheckBox do_not_show_this_again = new CheckBox(context);
do_not_show_this_again.setText(context.getString(R.string.msg_dont_show_again));
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
layout.addView(message);
layout.addView(do_not_show_this_again);
dialogBack.setView(layout);
```

Comment: Yes I have omitted the message and the checkbox is showing now. Thanks so much.

Comment: @adrian4aes you are welcome. also I update my answer with putting some code

Answer (score 1):

Your`items` array should be referenced with an integer id like `R.array.items`

At least according to the example on the [official guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

That would explain that element and its associated checkbox not showing up. I'm just surprised your IDE did not catch that.

Comment: I have changed this line dialogBack.setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.string_array_name, null,... but this didn't solved my problem.